# Excel - Invoice Export reorganzing for input into quickbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet that is exported from our POS.  I need to reformat it to suitable input format for quickbooks.

```
Quote No    Delivery Date   Patient Line 1  Price 1 Line 2  Price 2 Line 3  Price 3 Line 4  Price 4 Line 5  Price 5 Line 6  Price 6 Line 7  Price 7 Line 8  Price 8 Line 9  Price 9 Line 10 Price 10    Line 11 Price 11    Line 12 Price 12    Line 13 Price 13    Line 14 Price 14    Line 15 Price 15    Line 16 Price 16    Line 17 Price 17    Line 18 Price 18    Line 19 Price 19    Line 20 Price 20    Line 21 Price 21    Line 22 Price 22    Line 23 Price 23    Line 24 Price 24    Total
1234        10/10/15        ABC     p1l     $1.00   p2l      $1.00                                                  p1r     $1.00   p2r     $1.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               $4.00
```

What I need to happen is for each line and price to a be a new line for example

```
Quote No   Delivery Date    Patient     Product     Price     Total
1234       10/10/15         ABC         P1L         $1.00     $4.00
1234       10/10/15         ABC         P2L         $1.00     $4.00
1234       10/10/15         ABC         P1R         $1.00     $4.00
1234       10/10/15         ABC         P2R         $1.00     $4.00
.....
2222       10/15/15         YZD        ..............................
```

So for each product on the invoice I need a new row created with the customer information duplicated as well as the total.

There are 24 available slots for product/price combinations and many of them are often blank and there will be blank product/price combos between other filled product/price combos as the POS puts specific sales items in specific columns and not all sales contain all items. So for those blank spots we can't have a blank line created.

Range of the columns are A:AZ

It wouldn't contain more than a 1000 rows

Hope this isn't too much to ask.

Thanks

Comment: `Hope this isn't too much to ask.` Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a VBA function which should do as you describe. The function checks every cell in the used range to see if it is not empty and below a header that contains 'line'. If the cell does contains this data, it takes the relevant data and puts it into a new sheet named `ws` temporarily. Once all the data is tranferred it deletes the original sheet and renames the the sheet to be the same as the original, giving the impression of a modified sheet. I haven't been able to test it extensively but it should work. The function is as follows:

```
    Function NormalizeData(shtnm As String)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim rowcount As Long
        Dim colcount As Long
        Dim colnum As Long
        Dim rownum As Long
        Dim tgtrow As Long
        Sheets.Add.Name = "ws"
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Sheets("ws")
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Quote No"
        ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Delivery Date"
        ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Patient"
        ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Product"
        ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Price"
        ws.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Total"
        With Sheets(shtnm)
        rowcount = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        colcount = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        For rownum = 2 To rowcount
            For colnum = 1 To colcount
                tgtrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                If .Cells(1, colnum) Like "*Line *" And .Cells(rownum, colnum) <> "" Then
                        ws.Cells(tgtrow, 1).Value = .Cells(rownum, 1).Value
                        ws.Cells(tgtrow, 2).Value = .Cells(rownum, 2).Value
                        ws.Cells(tgtrow, 3).Value = .Cells(rownum, 3).Value
                        ws.Cells(tgtrow, 4).Value = .Cells(rownum, colnum).Value
                        ws.Cells(tgtrow, 5).Value = .Cells(rownum, colnum + 1).Value
                        ws.Cells(tgtrow, 6).Value = .Cells(rownum, colcount).Value
                End If
            Next colnum
        Next rownum
        .Delete
        End With
        ws.Name = shtnm
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Function
```

This is the sub to call the tranformation:

```
    Sub CallNormalise()
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Call NormalizeData("Sheet1")
    End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Good. I'm glad. if you accept the answer then it will help other who have a similar or the same problem...